# Function that counts duplicates in list and returns list with each pairs

Tags: python, list, function, printing, duplicates

I am having a question regarding the following issue. I want to get a function which is called `duplicated_pairs()` that helps me to find all pairs of duplicates in a list of numbers and returns the list with the pairs.

For example, if the input is:

```py
list_1 = [0,0,1,1,1,2,4]
```

My expected output would be

```py
[[0,0],[1,1,1]]
```

The code I tried:

```py
import collections 

def duplicated_pairs(x):
    temp = collections.Counter(x)
    res = [[i] * j for i, j in temp.items()] 
    print(str(res))

list_1 = [0,0,1,1,1,2,4]
duplicated_pairs(list_1)
```

I guess this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that runs in O(nlog(n))

```
def duplicates(A):
  N=len(A)
  dup=False
  final_list=[]
  list_of_same_elements=[]
  for i in range(1,N):
    prev=A[i-1]
    cur=A[i]
    if(cur==prev):
      if(dup==False):
        list_of_same_elements=[prev,cur]
        dup=True
      else:
        list_of_same_elements.append(cur)
    else:
      if(dup==True):
        final_list.append(list_of_same_elements)
        list_of_same_elements=[]
        dup=False
  return final_list

A=[0,0,1,1,1,2,4]
A.sort()
print(duplicates(A))
```

Comment: Many thanks! However your code didnt work for me if I adjust my list to: A_2 = [0,0,1,1,1,2,4, 7, 7, 8]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to regroup the values, and then simply filter the lists of value that weren't duplicate. For example:

```py
import collections 

def duplicated_pairs(x):
    temp = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for value in x:
        temp[value].append(value)
    print([lst for lst in temp.values() if len(lst) > 1])

list_1 = [0,0,1,1,1,2,4]
duplicated_pairs(list_1)
```

Would prints:

```py
[[0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```